# couldn't sync local folder to gcloud

Tags: python, gcloud, gsutil

Goal : To sync the local machine directory to the gcloud bucket.

I have authenticated with the service account using the key file and even check the auth using `gcloud auth list` but wasn't able to sync the file using `gsutil rsync -r data gs://mybucket/data`
.
I have attached the screenshot of the error.
[image]

PS: Dont link the issue to another issues. I have tried all the possible way and have went those lots of git and stack pages and still couldn't find a solution.

Comment: yeah. 
Error log : 
Enabling service [iam.googleapis.com] on project [861487771178]...
ERROR: (gcloud.iam.service-accounts.get-iam-policy) PERMISSION_DENIED: The caller does not have permission

Comment: @rsalinas problem with the permission. but i have authenticated the login with gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file = [Key] and even checked the gcloud auth list and the activated account was shown.

Comment: Yes, I can see that the correct service account is being used, but it seems that the account lacks permissions. That's why I am asking if you can share which roles the account has assigned.

Comment: How do I check that ? @rsalinas

Comment: With the command `gcloud projects get-iam-policy [Project-ID]`, you should receive a list of the roles assigned to the accounts in your project. You can look for the service account, and then share the roles it have. I deleted a previous comment because I shared the wrong command.

Comment: ERROR: (gcloud.projects.get-iam-policy) PERMISSION_DENIED: The caller does not have permission.... This is what i get when i run  get-iam-policy. @rsalinas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(*)After the authentication of the service account : `gcloud auth activate-service-account [ACCOUNT] --key-file=KEY_FILE`

(*)Activate the account: `glcoud auth list` *and activate the account with following code that was shown below.*

(*)config the gsutil : `gsutil config`

(*)Provide the authentication code

This worked for me.